# ActionScript 2, htmlText, img-tag and center-tag

Tags: html, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm trying to out an image into a Flash ActionScript 2 dynamic text box.
This does work by putting `<img ... />` into htmlText-code. But I cannot center the image on a line with the `<center>`...`</center>` tags.

Can anyone help me out on how to accomplish the following:

TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT

```
          IMG
```

TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT

in a htmlText-field in ActionScript 2.

Comment: have you apply width for image in css or can you share your code

Comment: I have not applied any width yet on images. Currently I have the following HTML code:

<p>Lipsum</p>
<p><center><img src="..." /></center></p>
<p>Lipsum</p>

Comment: Ghost Answer -> Does it help, if I put width on my images?

Comment: Can anyone give me a example of html-code, which should center and image in a htmlText-field in AS2?

Comment: Yes, of course. My html code looks like this: <p>Lipsum</p> <p><center><img src="..." /></center></p> <p>Lipsum</p>

Comment: try this code. I hope this will help you. if not then reply. <div style ="width:150px;"> 
<p>Lipsum</p>
 <p >
<center>

<img src="..." /></center></p> 
<p>Lipsum</p>
</div>

Comment: Ghost Answer: It doesn't help. As you can see on my homepage: http://test.leifsigersen.com/#/blog the image is not centered. My code is placed in http://test.leifsigersen.com/xml/blog.php. In AS2 I retrieve the content from the XML-document's item "text".

Comment: I've tried to make the images as wide as the text area, see example: test.leifsigersen.com/#/blog However, there's still some problems with some text in the right side. HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with div that id wrapper

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<about title="Blog">
<title>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</title>
<thumb></thumb>
<text>
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 500px;">
<p>04/19-2012 - Test with images...</p>
<p>This image is not centered, as it should be...</p>
<p>
    <center>
        <img src="/uploads/dmbtest.gif" alt="" width="210" height="100" />
    </center>
</p>
<p>This is text after the image, which should be placed just below the image and not next to it :(</p>
<p>##################################################</p>
</div>
</text><optionalText><![CDATA[]]></optionalText></about>
```

Its working fine

Comment: It does need to have CDATA around the content of the text-tag. I've changed the XML on the homepage, as you can see here: http://test.leifsigersen.com/xml/blog_test.xml. However, it still fails to center the image: http://test.leifsigersen.com/#/blog

Comment: Ghost Answer -> do you have any idea of why it doesn't work? Do you have a .fla/.swf file where it does work?

Comment: Do you have an example where it works? Then I can match your example with mine?

Comment: I've tried to make the images as wide as the text area, see example: test.leifsigersen.com/#/blog
However, there's still some problems with some text in the right side. HELP!